# Where can I get a shapefile for English Local Education Authorities

Tags: geospatial, uk

I am looking to map some data to local education authorities in england. I've found map examples here: http://schoolswebdirectory.co.uk/maps.php?region=all and https://www.haven.com/download/uk-summer-holiday-map-2014.pdf

Description is here: https://data.gov.uk/dataset/local-education-authorities-ew-apr-2009-names-and-codes

But I can't seem to find a shapefile to use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/c4a62d87de9f4b6087cf5f1515d5a0c1_0?geometry=-8.141%2C54.005%2C4.933%2C55.897&uiTab=table&orderByFields=ctyua14nm+ASC_ from the ONS Open Geography Portal appears to be along the right lines.

**UPDATE**: the link above appears to be broken, this links now works for 2014 data:
https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/ons::ctyua-dec-2014-full-extent-boundaries-in-england-and-wales/explore

And this works for 2023 data (a few areas have been renamed since 2014):
https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/34cae3dd946847f78b6dfc6bd5add3c7